# I can't select objects when I deactivate overlays

Tags: customization, select

When I deactivate overlays I can not see any lines on the object and I can't see wich vertices, edges or faces I have selected. I just started using blender yesterday  and I made a model. Everything worked fine, but then I think I accidently pressed a butten or clicked something and since then I cant work  on without overlays anymore because I cant select anything. How can I change this ?

Also it doesnt work if I reload the factory preferences because I didnt save the preferences at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing an image of your screen this is a guess, but you probably clicked on the Overlay icon in the image below. Click again and see if everything reappears.
[image]